# If I link foo.so to bar.so, do private shared library dependencies need to be found at compile time?

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

Using cmake language, say I create a target `foo`, and link it to `libbar.so`. `libbar.so` was already compiled on a different platform with a cmake PRIVATE depedency on `libbaz.so`. So the dependency chain is

`foo ----> libbar --(PRIVATE)--> libbaz`

Does `libbaz.so` need to be present on the system when I compile `foo` and link it with `libbar`? My understanding is that I can compile and link `foo` without `libbaz`, and then find `libbaz` at `foo`s runtime on a different platform using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. In other words, my hunch is that `libbaz` is only a runtime, and not compile time dependency.

But my current design for a large build system is dependent on this hunch being correct, so I want to double check.

Comment: Yes. You don't use libbaz, but libbar does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### General linking by the compiler toolchain

In general it depends on how `libbaz` got linked to `libbar`.

If `libbaz` got statically linked when building `libbar` then there are no compile or runtime dependencies at build-time of `foo` to `libbaz`. This is due to the fact that statically linked code gets "copied" into the file that links it (when no special hacks or other *dark magic* is used).

If `libbaz` got dynamically linked when building `libbar` then `libbaz` is (only) a runtime dependency at build-time of `foo`.

| final library | linking | middle library | linking | first library | runtime dependencies |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| foo | statically | libbar | statically | libbaz | none |
| foo | statically | libbar | dynamically | libbaz | libbaz |
| foo | dynamically | libbar | statically | libbaz | libbar |
| foo | dynamically | libbar | dynamically | libbaz | libbar, libbaz |

There is an exception. But it should not apply in your specified scenario. If `libbar` dynamically loads another library (like `libbaz`) via Windows-API [LoadLibrary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibraryw) or Unix/Linux/...-API [dlopen](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen) then the linker does not have any information about this dependency at build-time. In this case it is a dynamic runtime dependency by code.

### Public / Private

In this case as you are using CMake it is a terminology of CMake. This is only meaningful when defining dependencies in CMake (mainly via [target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html)).

| CMake target | linking | CMake target or library | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| libbar | private | libbaz | *libbar* gets *libbaz'* includes, etc. at compile-time and as linking library at link-time. |
| libbar | public | libbaz | *libbar* gets *libbaz'* includes, etc. at compile-time and as linking library at link-time. Libraries using *libbar* are also getting the interface portion of *libbaz* (interface includes, libs, etc.). |
| libbar | interface | libbaz | *libbar* does not use *libbaz* at all. Libraries using *libbar* are getting the interface portion of *libbaz* (interface includes, libs, etc.). |